# Is there no Pareto-optimal Shotgun game?

Tags: game-theory

I thought about an example game to use to illustrate what "Pareto-optimal" means, and I can't think of an outcome of Shotgun game (rock, paper, scissors) played by three players that would be Pareto-optiomal.

I was just wondering whether I'm not mistaking?

PS. I saw this question: [Nash Equilibria for zero-sum games (Rock Paper Scissors)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/254908/nash-equilibria-for-zero-sum-games-rock-paper-scissors) but it's about the overall optimal strategy, not Pareto-optimal.

The scoring is like this:

- When you draw against another player, you get 0 points.
- When you win against another player, you get 1 point.
- When you loose against another player, you get -1 point.
- The score is a sum of two outcomes of your match against two other players. Example: player A has scissors, player B has scissors and player C has rock, then players A and B have each 0 *(from draw)* - 1 *(defeated by the rock)*, i.e. both have -1. Player C has 2 *(since that player defeated both A and B and both victories give this player a +1)*.

Oh... but now that I've described it, I think that every such game would be Pareto-optimal, because improving one's scoring will necessary worsen the scoring of someone else. Ouch, sorry :(

Comment: What are the rules?

Comment: @Arnaud oh, I'll update the question now.

Comment: Your question and your answer are both interesting !

Comment: @wvxvw: Why not either write up your answer and accept it (so that people can tell it has been answered), or delete it?

Comment: This was flagged as belonging on Cross-Validated, but it really does not seem suited to that site. There is no game theory site, so it should stay here (besides, it has been answered).

Comment: @robjohn oh sure I will. Sorry, busy evening in the office.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I misapprehended the conditions I put for the problem, but after more thought it becomes apparent that, in fact any shotgun game is [Pareto-optimal](http://www.gametheory.net/dictionary/ParetoOptimal.html) because whenever you improve a score of one of the players, you necessarily worsen the score of some other player.